# Scss parent selector, hover and active

Tags: sass, hover

I am very new to Scss and I am trying to have some logic whereby when I hover on the a element I get an underlying bar to appear and if I select that element in the nav menu the bar stays fixed.

I have the following, but I do not seem to correctly nest the active action:

```
nav {
  max-width:100%;
  background:  lightblue;
  ul{
    background: yellow;
    li {
      background: yellow;
      text-align: center;
      a {
        color: red;
        display: inline-block;
      }
        &:hover { background: linear-gradient(to top, green 4px, transparent 0); }
        &:active { background: linear-gradient(to top, green 4px, transparent 0); }
    }
  }
}
```

Is that how I correctly use hover and active on the a element? Can you help? I am rather confused about it.

Thank you,

P.

Comment: Post your html too

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your `:hover` and `:active` selectors are related to li `element`. You should put these rules to `a` section.

```
nav {
  max-width:100%;
  background: lightblue;

  ul{
    background: yellow;

    li {
      background: yellow;
      text-align: center;

      a { // <a> starts here
        color: red;
        display: inline-block;

        &:hover { 
          background: linear-gradient(to top, green 4px, transparent 0); 
        }

        &:active { 
          background: linear-gradient(to top, green 4px, transparent 0); 
        }
      } // and ends here
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: if your `:hover` and `:active` styles are the same, your can avoid duplication by using `&:hover, &:active { ... }`